# Worried thing about Magento version at current Question

Tags: discussion, tags

From last few days,i have observing  user **did not mention magento version in his/her questions**. That make ***`difficult to answer those question`***

**Example:**

[REST API - categories by store view code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114522/rest-api-categories-by-store-view-code)

[Why is my XML not working?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114533/why-is-my-xml-not-working) [i  have add basic of content]

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114507/a-new-slide-static-block [i have added]

**My question:**

How to resolve this version issue so that users can answer those question.

*My point of view below may be one of solution*

- Put a comment to question engagement,asking user to specify
- review those question content put a magento version tab basic of
  content
- Leave as there

**Please put your valuable view**

Comment: It's gr8 that you have lot of concern on other users problems, as posting one tag is mandatary when asking question, if we make version also as mandatary, than its going to be very helpfull for  guys like you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know that this needs to be addressed in Meta. I've tried previously to curb adding the Magento version number in titles, but that was struck down. As of now I suggest a comment is all that is needed to tag these questions. M2 is still quite new, and as of now there are only 800 active sites using it. This means we should assume that all questions are M1 questions unless they state otherwise.

Now, about the questions you raised as examples:

- Q1 is now tagged with M2
- Q2, as you stated, could be obviously M1 because of the layout format
- Q3 is also obviously M1 based on the screenshots provided

So I would continue along how you're doing currently - let's categorize where it seems ambiguous. But otherwise assume M1 for the time being.

Comment: thanks @philwinkle for ur feedback....

Comment: This raised   at my mind because of ..i feel less interest on those question. many time question content does not  clearly point the version and some case there are different reply need on basic of Q.So,I was asking about version but user does not replied  and the point is only worry to me.Bye way your suggest to good.

Comment: only 800 sites are using it, that's fantastic information. seems you  know top to bottom in magento :-)

Comment: @BabyinMagento it was on stage at imagine :) https://twitter.com/benjaminrobie/status/720295820344438786

Comment: @philwinkle That's nice. but is there anything that you don't know in magento [it's not only about concepts, whatever!.... ] ? i am sure you don't have answer for this :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think it's a new problem, it has always been like this, it's just that now that Magento 2 becomes bigger and more people use it, the differences between M1 and M2 raised that specific problem.

What I tend to do for questions that do not require loads of code to be answered, is to post solutions for both M1 and M2, this way you ensure the question will be on topic.

On top of that I agree with the comment, definitely helps when you can't guess if the OP talks about M1 or M2.

Comment: ,thanks fore your view

Comment: Rapheal, post of two answers,is not good an idea.It is time consume>what ur thought?

Answer (score 1):

Very Good concern. You are a effective questioner.

Regarding this important topic, 
I would **recommend to the asker** to

- pick/write a tag (namely magento-1.9 or magento2 etc) on Tags line under the questioning field before clicking on `Post Your Question`.

To pick the Magento version tag, the **asker can easily choose** his/her **magento version from ajaxified list** of magento's version(onto **Tags line**) **down there**.

This way everyone can see the magento-version on bottom-zone of the question. :)

Comment: Thing is, I'm pretty sure no one has a way of modifying said form to include a "mandatory" Magento version tag. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. Yes, mentioning magento-version can also be included as mandatory so that it would be more precise to the answerer.